# (wrong-type-argument markerp nil) during shell-mode PDB tracking

Tags: python, emacs

With the built-in `python-mode` that comes with the standard distribution of Emacs, you can set up a hook so that a PDB session gets *tracked* when initiating through `shell-mode`:

```lisp
(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook
   'comint-output-filter-functions
   'python-pdbtrack-comint-output-filter-function t))
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
```

Normally, this means Python will open the source code that corresponds to the current interpreter location. Pretty smart!

For some reason, from experimentation possibly having to do with using a custom theme, Emacs can get into a bad state such that we get an error when moving to a new Python source file.

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument markerp nil)
  python-pdbtrack-unset-tracked-buffer()
  python-pdbtrack-comint-output-filter-function(#("\15\33[K\15(Pdb) " 0 11 (field output)))
  run-hook-with-args(python-pdbtrack-comint-output-filter-function #("\15\33[K\15(Pdb) " 0 11 (field output)))
  comint-output-filter(#<process shell> #("\15\33[K\15(Pdb) " 0 11 (field output)))
```

The error happens somewhere inside this function:

```lisp
(defun python-pdbtrack-unset-tracked-buffer ()
  "Untrack currently tracked buffer."
  (when (buffer-live-p python-pdbtrack-tracked-buffer)
    (with-current-buffer python-pdbtrack-tracked-buffer
      (set-marker overlay-arrow-position nil)))
  (setq python-pdbtrack-tracked-buffer nil))
```

Emacs becomes more or less unusable in this state, corrupting most buffers with the error message.

How to dig deeper to figure out what this issue is about?

My current steps to debug the issue has been to open up emacs using `-Q` and I have been able to trigger the issue only when enabling a custom theme (on the other hand, reverting back to the default theme doesn't fix things up).

Comment: From the error, it looks like `overlay-arrow-position` is `nil` at some point when `python-pdbtrack-unset-tracked-buffer` is called. To dig deeper, you can debug functions with `edebug-defun` or trace with `trace-function`. You could set a conditional breakpoint `edebug-set-conditional-breakpoint` in that function to trigger when `overlay-arrow-position` is nil

Comment: While this is programming, you'll almost certainly find better resources at [emacs.se].

Comment: @Barmar oh dang didn't even realize there was an emacs-specific site; I don't have any voting points to move tho ...